# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'

Tags: c#, combobox, video-capture, aforge, selectedindex

If this way I can list exist video capture devices:

```
    foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
    }
```

How to avoid exception in case if device just does not exist on machine:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is
>   not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.  Parameter name: SelectedIndex at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you add Device.Name, check if it exists in the first place

```
if(Device!= null){
     comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
}
```

Also, create a boolean that indicates a device does not exist, and if it is found switch it to true. Something like bool devExist = false; and when device is not null, devExist = true.
Then you'd know if no device is there and you wouldn't try to access it if iti's not there   if(devExist) { //do something }